# How to secure azure worker role settings?

Tags: azure, encryption, connection-string

Say you want to store a password or connection string in azure settings. What are the options?

I found a couple articles [1] about using custom config provider (namely PKCS12) and encrypted data ends up in web.config file rather than .cscfg file.

My ideal solution would use a certificate to encrypt the value in .cscfg file, I'd upload such certificate, then I'd just call something like GetDecrypted("myazureaettingkeyname", "certificate-thumbprint")

Is that feasible and recommendaded?

[1] http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2010/09/09/securing-your-connection-string-in-windows-azure-part-3/

UPDATE:
I submitted a suggestion at Azure's User Voice: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/9025255-certificate-based-settings-encryption